# Compiler having trouble with referencing an assembly

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

I've created a Class Library project called Core.  The default namespace is XXX.Tasker.Core.

I've created another Console project which references Core.  In my Main() I've got some calls to stuff inside the Core but I'm getting an error:

> The type or namespace name 'Core' does
>   not exist in the namespace
>   'XXXX.Tasker' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)

The only thing I can think of is that the fact my assembly name is Core might be confusing it.. but that really doesn't make much sense.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: I renamed my namespace to be XXX.Tasker.CoreN and still no luck..

Comment: For fun I made the Console app reference everything the Core does due to some other ppl getting this message with MS things and having a missing reference.  No change.

Comment: There's no reason having the name 'core' should cause your compilation to fail. It sounds like this is an error with the namespace definition for the 'core' assembly you created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that Core was compiled as .Net Framework 4 and the Console was .Net Framework 4 Client Profile.  Apparently you'll just get really weird errors instead of a proper notification when this occurs.. thanks MS! ;)